# Way to create mutiple, related boilerplate files via the commandline

Tags: templates, sed, makefile, boilerplate

A while ago I asked about something that would allow me to create boilerplate and was pointed towards [mush](https://github.com/jwerle/mush), but now I'm looking for something a little fancier that would allow me transform the variables, use variables in filenames, and would allow me to define a directory of files as a single template.

My goal here is to be able to run something like `cat ./react_component.ms | name=MyComponent mush` and generate a directory that looks like this:

```
my_component/
  index.js
  my_component.jsx
  my_component.css
  my_component.spec
  my_component.md
```

Each file would have boilerplate based on the variables entered:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello There</h1>;
  }
}
```

While poking around more recently, I got pointed towards [sagui](https://github.com/saguijs/sagui#features) and [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), but both projects seem pretty heavy and intended for creating boilerplate for an entire project, not just for a a single component.

Here's the type of thing I was imagining:

```
templates/
  react-component.vars   <--- would define `snake_name` based on `name`
  react-component.ms/
    {{snake_name}}/
      index.js.ms
      {{snake_name}}.jsx.ms
      {{snake_name}}.css.ms
      {{snake_name}}.spec.ms
      {{snake_name}}.md.ms
```

Below would be inside `{{snake_name}}.jsx.ms`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default {{name}} extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello There</h1>;
  }
}
```

Before I go ahead and make something like this/try to add on to `mush`, does anybody know if there's another templating library that already does this?

Comment: Tagged with `makefile`.

Comment: @stevesliva: Why `makefile` tag is needed here? Note that **question** tags are unrelated to utilities suggested in the *answer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making an npm package called [Genierator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/genierator).

Answer (score 1):

`make` would seem to be what you want.  It's a bit arcane to a new user, but you could do something like this:

```
# This is a Makefile

default:
    mkdir -p $(name)
    make $(files)

files := $(patsubst $(name)/my_component.%, $(name)/$(name).%, $(patsubst templates/%,$(name)/%,$(wildcard templates/*)))

$(name)/%: templates/%
    sed -e 's/my_component/$(name)/g' $< > $@

$(name)/$(name).%: templates/my_component.%
    sed -e 's/my_component/$(name)/g' $< > $@
```

would allow this with `make name=fred`:

```
$ make name=fred
mkdir -p fred
make fred/index.js  fred/fred.jsx
sed -e 's/my_component/fred/g' templates/index.js > fred/index.js
sed -e 's/my_component/fred/g' templates/my_component.jsx > fred/fred.jsx
```

Given the `Makefile` above and a templates directory as suggested in the output above.

Comment: Make is pretty close, but not quite. I ended up making my own thing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/genierator